# Query XML Data using Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have some xml files that I need to parse and convert to relational data. The data is to be stored in SQL Server. I get the files from different sources and I am running into trouble with one of them because the segment for the purchase order number is repeated. The trouble that I am having is that it creates a duplicate record or row. Here is what the xml looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pt:PTShipmentNotification  xmlns:cmn="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:commontypes"     xmlns:pt="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:product_track">
<pt:MessageBody>
<pt:ShipmentTransaction>
<cmn:ShipmentIdentifiers>
<cmn:ShipmentId type="ShipmentNumber">22584</cmn:ShipmentId>
<cmn:ShipmentId type="BillOfLading">2584226516</cmn:ShipmentId>
</cmn:ShipmentIdentifiers>
</pt:ShipmentTransaction>
<pt:ShipmentItemDetails>
<cmn:LineItemNumber>1</cmn:LineItemNumber>
<cmn:LotNumber>FT0109</cmn:LotNumber>
<cmn:OrderNDC type="NDC542">49884066009</cmn:OrderNDC>
<cmn:ExpirationDate>2018-09-30</cmn:ExpirationDate>
<cmn:SalesQuantity quantityUnitOfMeasure="EA">12</cmn:SalesQuantity>
<pt:ReferenceDocuments>
<cmn:BusinessDocument type="PurchaseOrder">024136</cmn:BusinessDocument>
<cmn:DocumentDate>2016-02-03</cmn:DocumentDate>
</pt:ReferenceDocuments>
<pt:ReferenceDocuments>
<cmn:BusinessDocument type="PurchaseOrder">024136</cmn:BusinessDocument>
<cmn:DocumentDate>2016-02-03</cmn:DocumentDate>
</pt:ReferenceDocuments>
</pt:ShipmentItemDetails>
<pt:ShipmentItemDetails>
<cmn:LineItemNumber>2</cmn:LineItemNumber>
<cmn:LotNumber>FN0043</cmn:LotNumber>
<cmn:OrderNDC type="NDC542">49884082710</cmn:OrderNDC>
<cmn:ExpirationDate>2019-01-31</cmn:ExpirationDate>
<cmn:SalesQuantity quantityUnitOfMeasure="EA">36</cmn:SalesQuantity>
<pt:ReferenceDocuments>
<cmn:BusinessDocument type="PurchaseOrder">024136</cmn:BusinessDocument>
<cmn:DocumentDate>2016-02-03</cmn:DocumentDate>
</pt:ReferenceDocuments>
<pt:ReferenceDocuments>
<cmn:BusinessDocument type="Invoice">024136</cmn:BusinessDocument>
<cmn:DocumentDate>2016-02-03</cmn:DocumentDate>
</pt:ReferenceDocuments>
</pt:ShipmentItemDetails>
</pt:MessageBody>
</pt:PTShipmentNotification>
```

Here is the query that I use to load the file into an xml variable and then query through SQL Server Management Studio. In production I do it using SSIS.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Files\in\badxml.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:commontypes' AS cmn,
    'urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:product_track' AS pt 
)



select 

    T.data.value('@type', 'varchar(20)') AS ShipType,
    T.data.value('.', 'varchar(35)') AS ShipNum,
    n.value('../cmn:LineItemNumber[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS LineItem,
    n.value('../cmn:OrderNDC[1]/@type', 'varchar(20)' ) AS OrderNDC,


    n.value('../cmn:OrderNDC[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS NDC,
    n.value('../cmn:LotNumber[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS Lot,
    n.value('../cmn:SalesQuantity[1]/@quantityUnitOfMeasure','VARCHAR(30)') AS UOM,
    n.value('../cmn:SalesQuantity[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS QTY,
    n.value('cmn:BusinessDocument[0]','VARCHAR(50)') AS PO,


    GETDATE() ProcessedDt,
    0 ProcessedFlag,
    @XmlFile

from
    @XmlFile.nodes('pt:PTShipmentNotification/pt:MessageBody/pt:ShipmentTransaction/cmn:ShipmentIdentifiers/cmn:ShipmentId') T(data)
CROSS APPLY @XmlFile.nodes('pt:PTShipmentNotification/pt:MessageBody/pt:ShipmentItemDetails/pt:ReferenceDocuments')  x1(n)

WHERE 
    T.data.value('@type', 'varchar(20)') = 'ShipmentNumber' 

    AND n.value('cmn:BusinessDocument[1]/@type','VARCHAR(50)') = 'PurchaseOrder'
```

Referring to the xml above, If the second occurrence of the purchase order number is called something else such as invoice number (as it usually is), then there is no issue. I get only one record or row per line item number. I am trying to get the sender to fix the file but I am also interested in being able to revise the code to handle the issue. So for line item one in the above xml I get two records. For line item two I only get one record. Does anyone have any suggestions for modifying the query to correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try cross applying to only a single row, instead of trying to filter in the where.

```
CROSS APPLY @XmlFile.nodes('pt:PTShipmentNotification/pt:MessageBody/pt:ShipmentItemDetails/pt:ReferenceDocuments[@type=''PurchaseOrder''][1]')  x1(n)
```

Remove the where filter on PurchaseOrder.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Files\in\badxml.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:commontypes' AS cmn,
    'urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:product_track' AS pt 
)



select 

    T.data.value('@type', 'varchar(20)') AS ShipType,
    T.data.value('.', 'varchar(35)') AS ShipNum,
    n.value('../cmn:LineItemNumber[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS LineItem,
    n.value('../cmn:OrderNDC[1]/@type', 'varchar(20)' ) AS OrderNDC,


    n.value('../cmn:OrderNDC[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS NDC,
    n.value('../cmn:LotNumber[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS Lot,
    n.value('../cmn:SalesQuantity[1]/@quantityUnitOfMeasure','VARCHAR(30)') AS UOM,
    n.value('../cmn:SalesQuantity[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS QTY,
    n.value('cmn:BusinessDocument[0]','VARCHAR(50)') AS PO,


    GETDATE() ProcessedDt,
    0 ProcessedFlag,
    @XmlFile

from
    @XmlFile.nodes('pt:PTShipmentNotification/pt:MessageBody/pt:ShipmentTransaction/cmn:ShipmentIdentifiers/cmn:ShipmentId') T(data)
CROSS APPLY @XmlFile.nodes('pt:PTShipmentNotification/pt:MessageBody/pt:ShipmentItemDetails/pt:ReferenceDocuments[@type=''PurchaseOrder''][1]')  x1(n)

WHERE 
    T.data.value('@type', 'varchar(20)') = 'ShipmentNumber'
```

Comment: Thanks your answer was very helpful! As written your Cross Apply resulted in no records returned but I made a change and it seems to be working now. Here is what I am using now:

Comment: CROSS APPLY @XmlFile.nodes('pt:PTShipmentNotification/pt:MessageBody/pt:ShipmentItemDetails/pt:ReferenceDocuments[cmn:BusinessDocument[1]/@type=''PurchaseOrder''][1]')  x1(n)